# Spark's amnesia of parquet partitions when cached in-memory (native spark cache)

Tags: apache-spark, caching, parquet

I am working on some batch processing with Spark, reading data from a partitioned parquet file which is around 2TB. Right now, I am caching the whole file, in-memory, since I need to restrict the reading of the same parquet file, multiple times (given the way, we are analyzing the data).

Till some time back, the code is working fine. Recently, we have added use-cases which needs to work on some selective partitions (like average of a metric for the last 2 years where the complete data spawns across 6+ years).

When we started taking metrics for the execution times, we have observed that the use-case, which will work on a subset of partitioned data, is also taking similar time when compared to the time taken by the use-case which requires to work on complete data.

So, my question is that whether Spark's in-memory caching honors partitions of a Parquet file i.e., will spark holds the partition information even after caching the data, in-memory ?

Note: Since this is really a general question about Spark's processing style, I didn't added any metrics or the code.

Comment: Partitioning is automatically inferred from your folder structure, see here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery

Comment: @mtoto I am sorry, I didn't get you. My question is more in terms of, "how the data, that is cached, represented in memory". Will it hold the same partition information even after cached i.e., can spark skip partitions during an operation that is performed on an in-memory (cached) RDD/Dataframe/Dataset? Please let me know if my intent is not clear, still.

Comment: if you intend to perform a query on a subset of the dataframe, you should only cache the subset.

Comment: @mtoto Totally, agree with you on caching the data that is only required for the query. My real question is not about, "how to solve the problem" but more of "how the data is represented in cache and how spark traverses through the partitions, if your query demands a subset of partitions" ? Assume, a case where you have to query same data twice (as part of a single spark job), one for complete data set and the other for a smaller subset.